# Unsplit a face in an object or reconnect a face

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

I'm new to using this app so I'm not really certain what happened, but I think while I was trying to resize or move a face on the y-axis in *Edit Mode*, I hit <kbd>Y</kbd> on the face and split it. And now if I try to move it, it will move separate from the head entirely. Whenever or however I did this, I can't undo it. Is there a way to reconnect the face back to the block?

Example of the face before I do anything with it:
[image: face on block]

Example of the face when I try to move it with <kbd>G</kbd>
[image]

Comment: If you've not done too much else, CTRL-Z will undo each action back to the limit of the undo buffer which is set via Edit > Preferences > System > Memory & Limits > Undo Steps.

Comment: If you can't undo, delete the face with `X` then select the edges around where the face was and hit `F`

Comment: If the face is back in the place where it was before, press A to select all, then M > Merge > By Distance: if you didn't move the face the vertices of the face should be in the same place as the ones where the ocnnection was and they get merged.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ah this worked! thank you so much!!